# How do i disable zoom in/out in Xamarin Forms Webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.ios

I have a problem about xamarin Forms Webview
I trying to disable zoom in webview so the user should not zoom.
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-enable-default-zooming-in-webview/ I red this document and implement it but I got one error in WebViewRenderer [error looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OYsj.jpg)
how can i solve it or how can i disable zoom?

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
```

namespace example.iOS
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
base.OnElementChanged(e);

```
        if (NativeView != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var webView = NativeView as UIWebView;

            if (webView == null)
                return;

            webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

**UPDATE :**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
```

namespace netraporMobileApp.iOS
{
public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WkWebViewRenderer
{
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
base.OnElementChanged(e);

```
        if (NativeView != null && e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var webView = NativeView as UIWebView;

            if (webView == null)
                return;

            webView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I changed like that but I can still zoom how can i disable zoom on IOS?

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the custom renderer for iOS, you could use `WkWebViewRenderer`.

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), 
typeof(CustomWebviewRenderer))]
  namespace App1.iOS
  {
  public class CustomWebviewRenderer: WkWebViewRenderer
  {
  protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnElementChanged(e);
     ........
    }
  } 
}
```

**Update:**

1. When you local the URL, the default zoom of WebView is disabled.
2. If you use the Html, you could configure the Html to disable it. Set `user-scalable=no` of `meta` tag in your Html.

   ```
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
   ```

Comment: I tried as you said but I can still zoom

Comment: The code in my reply could fix the error in the screenshot you provided. But according to the document, it is used to enable zoom.

Comment: so how can i disable it?

Comment: Check the update in my reply.

Comment: Hi Wendy,
It's work my android phone but it doesn't seem to work on ios devices what can i do?

Comment: The ways I provided in the reply are for iOS.